# ( method Glide.with(android.content.Context) is not applicable)

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

`Glide.with(context).load(user.getImageURL()).into(holder.profile_image);`
its not work its says (method `Glide.with(android.content.Context`) is not applicable )

```
public class UserAdopter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <UserAdopter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context ;
    private List<User> users ;




    public UserAdopter(Context context ,List<User> users){
        this.users = users ;
        this.context = context ;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user =  users.get(position);
        holder.username.setText(user.getUsername());
        if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
            holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }else {
            Glide.with(context).load(user.getImageURL()).into(holder.profile_image);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    public class  ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView username ;
        public ImageView profile_image ;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W8t0.jpg)

Comment: context should be from android.content.Context not your firebase context. you can use fragment, activity or application context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says it all:

[image]

Check your list of imports and make sure your Context is actually `android.content.Context`